# dbus dependency with yum

Tags: centos, yum, update, dbus

Whenever, I try and run yum update I get the following error:

```
[root@server ~]# yum update
Loaded plugins: dellsysid, fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror01.idc.hinet.net
 * extras: mirror01.idc.hinet.net
 * rpmforge: fr2.rpmfind.net
 * updates: mirror01.idc.hinet.net
Excluding Packages in global exclude list
Finished
Setting up Update Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package NetworkManager.x86_64 1:0.7.0-13.el5 set to be updated
---> Package NetworkManager-glib.x86_64 1:0.7.0-13.el5 set to be updated
---> Package SysVinit.x86_64 0:2.86-17.el5 set to be updated
---> Package acl.x86_64 0:2.2.39-8.el5 set to be updated
---> Package acpid.x86_64 0:1.0.4-12.el5 set to be updated
---> Package apr.x86_64 0:1.2.7-11.el5_6.5 set to be updated
---> Package aspell.x86_64 12:0.60.3-12 set to be updated
---> Package audit.x86_64 0:1.8-2.el5 set to be updated
---> Package audit-libs.x86_64 0:1.8-2.el5 set to be updated
---> Package audit-libs-python.x86_64 0:1.8-2.el5 set to be updated
---> Package authconfig.x86_64 0:5.3.21-7.el5 set to be updated
---> Package autofs.x86_64 1:5.0.1-0.rc2.163.el5 set to be updated
---> Package bash.x86_64 0:3.2-32.el5 set to be updated
---> Package bind.x86_64 30:9.3.6-20.P1.el5 set to be updated
---> Package bind-libs.x86_64 30:9.3.6-20.P1.el5 set to be updated
---> Package bind-utils.x86_64 30:9.3.6-20.P1.el5 set to be updated
---> Package binutils.x86_64 0:2.17.50.0.6-20.el5 set to be updated
---> Package centos-release.x86_64 10:5-8.el5.centos set to be updated
---> Package centos-release-notes.x86_64 0:5.8-0 set to be updated
---> Package coreutils.x86_64 0:5.97-34.el5_8.1 set to be updated
---> Package cpp.x86_64 0:4.1.2-52.el5 set to be updated
---> Package cpuspeed.x86_64 1:1.2.1-10.el5 set to be updated
---> Package crash.x86_64 0:5.1.8-1.el5.centos set to be updated
---> Package cryptsetup-luks.x86_64 0:1.0.3-8.el5 set to be updated
---> Package cups.x86_64 1:1.3.7-30.el5 set to be updated
---> Package cups-libs.x86_64 1:1.3.7-30.el5 set to be updated
---> Package curl.x86_64 0:7.15.5-15.el5 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: dbus = 1.1.2-15.el5_6 for package: dbus-libs
---> Package dbus.x86_64 0:1.1.2-16.el5_7 set to be updated
---> Package dbus-libs.x86_64 0:1.1.2-16.el5_7 set to be updated
---> Package device-mapper.x86_64 0:1.02.67-2.el5 set to be updated
---> Package device-mapper-event.x86_64 0:1.02.67-2.el5 set to be updated
---> Package device-mapper-multipath.x86_64 0:0.4.7-48.el5_8.1 set to be updated
---> Package dhclient.x86_64 12:3.0.5-31.el5 set to be updated
---> Package dmidecode.x86_64 1:2.11-1.el5 set to be updated
---> Package dmraid.x86_64 0:1.0.0.rc13-65.el5 set to be updated
---> Package dmraid-events.x86_64 0:1.0.0.rc13-65.el5 set to be updated
---> Package dump.x86_64 0:0.4b41-6.el5 set to be updated
---> Package e2fsprogs.x86_64 0:1.39-33.el5 set to be updated
---> Package e2fsprogs-devel.x86_64 0:1.39-33.el5 set to be updated
---> Package e2fsprogs-libs.x86_64 0:1.39-33.el5 set to be updated
---> Package ecryptfs-utils.x86_64 0:75-8.el5 set to be updated
---> Package file.x86_64 0:4.17-21 set to be updated
---> Package finger.x86_64 0:0.17-33 set to be updated
---> Package firstboot-tui.x86_64 0:1.4.27.9-1.el5.centos set to be updated
---> Package freetype.x86_64 0:2.2.1-28.el5_7.2 set to be updated
---> Package freetype-devel.x86_64 0:2.2.1-28.el5_7.2 set to be updated
---> Package ftp.x86_64 0:0.17-37.el5 set to be updated
---> Package gamin.x86_64 0:0.1.7-10.el5 set to be updated
---> Package gamin-python.x86_64 0:0.1.7-10.el5 set to be updated
---> Package gawk.x86_64 0:3.1.5-15.el5 set to be updated
---> Package gcc.x86_64 0:4.1.2-52.el5 set to be updated
---> Package gcc-c++.x86_64 0:4.1.2-52.el5 set to be updated
---> Package glibc.i686 0:2.5-81.el5_8.1 set to be updated
---> Package glibc.x86_64 0:2.5-81.el5_8.1 set to be updated
---> Package glibc-common.x86_64 0:2.5-81.el5_8.1 set to be updated
---> Package glibc-devel.x86_64 0:2.5-81.el5_8.1 set to be updated
---> Package glibc-headers.x86_64 0:2.5-81.el5_8.1 set to be updated
---> Package gnutls.x86_64 0:1.4.1-7.el5_8.2 set to be updated
---> Package groff.x86_64 0:1.18.1.1-13.el5 set to be updated
---> Package gtk2.x86_64 0:2.10.4-21.el5_7.7 set to be updated
---> Package gzip.x86_64 0:1.3.5-13.el5.centos set to be updated
---> Package hmaccalc.x86_64 0:0.9.6-4.el5 set to be updated
---> Package htop.x86_64 0:1.0.1-2.el5.rf set to be updated
---> Package hwdata.noarch 0:0.213.26-1.el5 set to be updated
---> Package ifd-egate.x86_64 0:0.05-17.el5 set to be updated
---> Package initscripts.x86_64 0:8.45.42-1.el5.centos set to be updated
---> Package iproute.x86_64 0:2.6.18-13.el5 set to be updated
---> Package iptables.x86_64 0:1.3.5-9.1.el5 set to be updated
---> Package iptables-ipv6.x86_64 0:1.3.5-9.1.el5 set to be updated
---> Package iscsi-initiator-utils.x86_64 0:6.2.0.872-13.el5 set to be updated
---> Package kernel.x86_64 0:2.6.18-308.1.1.el5 set to be installed
---> Package kernel-headers.x86_64 0:2.6.18-308.1.1.el5 set to be updated
---> Package kpartx.x86_64 0:0.4.7-48.el5_8.1 set to be updated
---> Package krb5-devel.x86_64 0:1.6.1-70.el5 set to be updated
---> Package krb5-libs.x86_64 0:1.6.1-70.el5 set to be updated
---> Package krb5-workstation.x86_64 0:1.6.1-70.el5 set to be updated
---> Package ksh.x86_64 0:20100621-5.el5_8.1 set to be updated
---> Package kudzu.x86_64 0:1.2.57.1.26-3.el5.centos set to be updated
---> Package less.x86_64 0:436-9.el5 set to be updated
---> Package lftp.x86_64 0:3.7.11-7.el5 set to be updated
---> Package libX11.x86_64 0:1.0.3-11.el5_7.1 set to be updated
---> Package libX11-devel.x86_64 0:1.0.3-11.el5_7.1 set to be updated
---> Package libXcursor.x86_64 0:1.1.7-1.2 set to be updated
---> Package libacl.x86_64 0:2.2.39-8.el5 set to be updated
---> Package libgcc.x86_64 0:4.1.2-52.el5 set to be updated
---> Package libgomp.x86_64 0:4.4.6-3.el5.1 set to be updated
---> Package libpng.x86_64 2:1.2.10-16.el5_8 set to be updated
---> Package libpng-devel.x86_64 2:1.2.10-16.el5_8 set to be updated
---> Package libsmbios.x86_64 0:2.2.27-3.2.el5 set to be updated
---> Package libstdc++.x86_64 0:4.1.2-52.el5 set to be updated
---> Package libstdc++-devel.x86_64 0:4.1.2-52.el5 set to be updated
---> Package libsysfs.x86_64 0:2.1.0-1.el5 set to be updated
---> Package libusb.x86_64 0:0.1.12-6.el5 set to be updated
---> Package libvolume_id.x86_64 0:095-14.27.el5_7.1 set to be updated
---> Package libxml2.x86_64 0:2.6.26-2.1.15.el5_8.2 set to be updated
---> Package libxml2-python.x86_64 0:2.6.26-2.1.15.el5_8.2 set to be updated
---> Package logrotate.x86_64 0:3.7.4-12 set to be updated
---> Package lsof.x86_64 0:4.78-6 set to be updated
---> Package lvm2.x86_64 0:2.02.88-7.el5 set to be updated
---> Package m2crypto.x86_64 0:0.16-8.el5 set to be updated
---> Package man.x86_64 0:1.6d-2.el5 set to be updated
---> Package man-pages.noarch 0:2.39-20.el5 set to be updated
---> Package mcelog.x86_64 1:0.9pre-1.32.el5 set to be updated
---> Package mesa-libGL.x86_64 0:6.5.1-7.10.el5 set to be updated
---> Package mesa-libGL-devel.x86_64 0:6.5.1-7.10.el5 set to be updated
---> Package microcode_ctl.x86_64 2:1.17-1.56.el5 set to be updated
---> Package mkinitrd.x86_64 0:5.1.19.6-75.el5 set to be updated
---> Package mktemp.x86_64 3:1.5-24.el5 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: nash = 5.1.19.6-68.el5_6.1 for package: mkinitrd
---> Package nash.x86_64 0:5.1.19.6-75.el5 set to be updated
---> Package net-snmp.x86_64 1:5.3.2.2-17.el5 set to be updated
---> Package net-snmp-devel.x86_64 1:5.3.2.2-17.el5 set to be updated
---> Package net-snmp-libs.x86_64 1:5.3.2.2-17.el5 set to be updated
---> Package net-snmp-utils.x86_64 1:5.3.2.2-17.el5 set to be updated
---> Package net-tools.x86_64 0:1.60-82.el5 set to be updated
---> Package nfs-utils.x86_64 1:1.0.9-60.el5 set to be updated
---> Package nfs-utils-lib.x86_64 0:1.0.8-7.9.el5 set to be updated
---> Package nscd.x86_64 0:2.5-81.el5_8.1 set to be updated
---> Package nspr.x86_64 0:4.8.9-1.el5_8 set to be updated
---> Package nspr-devel.x86_64 0:4.8.9-1.el5_8 set to be updated
---> Package nss.x86_64 0:3.13.1-5.el5_8 set to be updated
---> Package nss-devel.x86_64 0:3.13.1-5.el5_8 set to be updated
---> Package nss-tools.x86_64 0:3.13.1-5.el5_8 set to be updated
---> Package nss_ldap.x86_64 0:253-49.el5 set to be updated
---> Package ntp.x86_64 0:4.2.2p1-15.el5.centos.1 set to be updated
---> Package numactl.x86_64 0:0.9.8-12.el5_6 set to be updated
---> Package oddjob.x86_64 0:0.27-12.el5 set to be updated
---> Package oddjob-libs.x86_64 0:0.27-12.el5 set to be updated
---> Package openldap.x86_64 0:2.3.43-25.el5 set to be updated
---> Package openssh.x86_64 0:4.3p2-82.el5 set to be updated
---> Package openssh-clients.x86_64 0:4.3p2-82.el5 set to be updated
---> Package openssh-server.x86_64 0:4.3p2-82.el5 set to be updated
---> Package openssl.i686 0:0.9.8e-22.el5_8.1 set to be updated
---> Package openssl.x86_64 0:0.9.8e-22.el5_8.1 set to be updated
---> Package openssl-devel.x86_64 0:0.9.8e-22.el5_8.1 set to be updated
---> Package pam_krb5.x86_64 0:2.2.14-22.el5 set to be updated
---> Package pam_pkcs11.x86_64 0:0.5.3-26.el5 set to be updated
---> Package pango.x86_64 0:1.14.9-8.el5.centos.3 set to be updated
---> Package parted.x86_64 0:1.8.1-29.el5 set to be updated
---> Package pciutils.x86_64 0:3.1.7-5.el5 set to be updated
---> Package perl.x86_64 4:5.8.8-38.el5 set to be updated
---> Package perl-Compress-Raw-Bzip2.x86_64 0:2.037-1.el5.rf set to be updated
---> Package perl-Compress-Raw-Zlib.x86_64 0:2.037-1.el5.rf set to be updated
---> Package perl-rrdtool.x86_64 0:1.4.7-1.el5.rf set to be updated
---> Package poppler.x86_64 0:0.5.4-19.el5 set to be updated
---> Package poppler-utils.x86_64 0:0.5.4-19.el5 set to be updated
---> Package popt.x86_64 0:1.10.2.3-28.el5_8 set to be updated
---> Package postgresql-libs.x86_64 0:8.1.23-1.el5_7.3 set to be updated
---> Package procps.x86_64 0:3.2.7-18.el5 set to be updated
---> Package proftpd.x86_64 0:1.3.4a-1.el5.rf set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Mail::Sendmail) for package: proftpd
---> Package python.x86_64 0:2.4.3-46.el5 set to be updated
---> Package python-ctypes.x86_64 0:1.0.2-3.el5 set to be updated
---> Package python-libs.x86_64 0:2.4.3-46.el5 set to be updated
---> Package python-smbios.x86_64 0:2.2.27-3.2.el5 set to be updated
---> Package rhpl.x86_64 0:0.194.1-2 set to be updated
---> Package rmt.x86_64 0:0.4b41-6.el5 set to be updated
---> Package rng-utils.x86_64 1:2.0-5.el5 set to be updated
---> Package rpm.x86_64 0:4.4.2.3-28.el5_8 set to be updated
---> Package rpm-build.x86_64 0:4.4.2.3-28.el5_8 set to be updated
---> Package rpm-devel.x86_64 0:4.4.2.3-28.el5_8 set to be updated
---> Package rpm-libs.x86_64 0:4.4.2.3-28.el5_8 set to be updated
---> Package rpm-python.x86_64 0:4.4.2.3-28.el5_8 set to be updated
---> Package rrdtool.x86_64 0:1.4.7-1.el5.rf set to be updated
---> Package rsh.x86_64 0:0.17-40.el5_7.1 set to be updated
---> Package rsync.x86_64 0:3.0.6-4.el5_7.1 set to be updated
---> Package ruby.x86_64 0:1.8.5-24.el5 set to be updated
---> Package ruby-libs.x86_64 0:1.8.5-24.el5 set to be updated
---> Package sblim-sfcb.x86_64 0:1.3.11-49.el5 set to be updated
---> Package sblim-sfcc.x86_64 0:2.2.2-49.el5 set to be updated
---> Package selinux-policy.noarch 0:2.4.6-327.el5 set to be updated
---> Package selinux-policy-targeted.noarch 0:2.4.6-327.el5 set to be updated
---> Package setup.noarch 0:2.5.58-9.el5 set to be updated
---> Package shadow-utils.x86_64 2:4.0.17-20.el5 set to be updated
---> Package smartmontools.x86_64 1:5.38-3.el5 set to be updated
---> Package smbios-utils-bin.x86_64 0:2.2.27-3.2.el5 set to be updated
---> Package smbios-utils-python.x86_64 0:2.2.27-3.2.el5 set to be updated
---> Package sos.noarch 0:1.7-9.62.el5 set to be updated
---> Package srvadmin-omilcore.x86_64 0:6.5.0-1.452.1.el5 set to be updated
---> Package strace.x86_64 0:4.5.18-11.el5_8 set to be updated
---> Package subversion.x86_64 0:1.6.11-7.el5_6.4 set to be updated
---> Package sudo.x86_64 0:1.7.2p1-13.el5 set to be updated
---> Package sysfsutils.x86_64 0:2.1.0-1.el5 set to be updated
---> Package syslinux.x86_64 0:3.11-7 set to be updated
---> Package system-config-network-tui.noarch 0:1.3.99.21-1.el5 set to be updated
---> Package talk.x86_64 0:0.17-31.el5 set to be updated
---> Package tar.x86_64 2:1.15.1-31.el5 set to be updated
---> Package traceroute.x86_64 3:2.0.1-6.el5 set to be updated
---> Package tzdata.x86_64 0:2012b-3.el5 set to be updated
---> Package udev.x86_64 0:095-14.27.el5_7.1 set to be updated
---> Package util-linux.x86_64 0:2.13-0.59.el5 set to be updated
---> Package vixie-cron.x86_64 4:4.1-81.el5 set to be updated
---> Package wget.x86_64 0:1.11.4-3.el5_8.1 set to be updated
---> Package xinetd.x86_64 2:2.3.14-16.el5 set to be updated
---> Package yp-tools.x86_64 0:2.9-2.el5 set to be updated
---> Package ypbind.x86_64 3:1.19-12.el5_6.1 set to be updated
---> Package yum.noarch 0:3.2.22-39.el5.centos set to be updated
---> Package yum-dellsysid.x86_64 0:2.2.27-3.2.el5 set to be updated
---> Package yum-fastestmirror.noarch 0:1.1.16-21.el5.centos set to be updated
---> Package zlib.x86_64 0:1.2.3-4.el5 set to be updated
---> Package zlib-devel.x86_64 0:1.2.3-4.el5 set to be updated
--> Running transaction check
--> Processing Dependency: dbus = 1.1.2-15.el5_6 for package: dbus-libs
--> Processing Dependency: nash = 5.1.19.6-68.el5_6.1 for package: mkinitrd
---> Package perl-Mail-Sendmail.noarch 0:0.79-1.2.el5.rf set to be updated
base/filelists                                                                                                                                                                        | 3.5 MB     00:00     
dell-omsa-indep/filelists                                                                                                                                                             | 195 kB     00:01     
dell-omsa-specific/filelists                                                                                                                                                          | 1.0 kB     00:00     
extras/filelists_db                                                                                                                                                                   | 224 kB     00:00     
rpmforge/filelists                                                                                                                                                                    | 4.8 MB     00:06     
updates/filelists_db                                                                                                                                                                  | 715 kB     00:00     
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
dbus-libs-1.1.2-15.el5_6.i386 from installed has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: dbus = 1.1.2-15.el5_6 is needed by package dbus-libs-1.1.2-15.el5_6.i386 (installed)
mkinitrd-5.1.19.6-68.el5_6.1.i386 from installed has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: nash = 5.1.19.6-68.el5_6.1 is needed by package mkinitrd-5.1.19.6-68.el5_6.1.i386 (installed)
Error: Missing Dependency: nash = 5.1.19.6-68.el5_6.1 is needed by package mkinitrd-5.1.19.6-68.el5_6.1.i386 (installed)
Error: Missing Dependency: dbus = 1.1.2-15.el5_6 is needed by package dbus-libs-1.1.2-15.el5_6.i386 (installed)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: package-cleanup --problems
                        package-cleanup --dupes
                        rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
The program package-cleanup is found in the yum-utils package.
```

I have tried running package-cleanup --dupes and package-cleanup --problems but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like dbus-libs.i386 and nash.i386 are installed. Remove them.

Comment: But nash.i386 is a dependency of mkinitrd. Is mkinitrd something that is needed at boot?

Comment: It's needed on kernel update. Make sure that you have nash.x86_64 installed.

Comment: By kernel update, do you mean only compiling a kernel? Do I need it for CentOS yum kernel updates?

Comment: You need it for updating via yum. You may need it if you compile your own kernel.